# Submit a manuscript to Geombinatorics journal

Tags: journal-publishing

I am going to submit a paper to [Geombinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geombinatorics). I found on their web page to know [How to Submit a Manuscript](http://www.uccs.edu/geombina/how-to-submit-a-manuscript.html)  the following:

> Your essay should be camera-ready in the following format:
>
> paper: 5.5" by 8.5"; hyphen on;
>   left, right, & top margins: 0.35"; bottom margin: 0.5";
>   font: Times New Roman scaleable 12 pt (if unavailable, use similar font from Times family); line spacing: single; Start with the title in bold, followed on the next line by the author(s)' name(s), followed by the address and e-mail.
>   Please note that thanks to MATHEMATICAL REVIEWS, ZENTRALBLATT FÜR MATHEMATIK, MATHEMATICS ABSTRACTS, many more colleagues throughout the world will learn about our geombinatorial games.

Actually I'm still confused with the above instructions. That would be great if someone could provide me a template latex codes in order get a standard format of Geombinatorics submission. I post here a `minimal example' to describe what format I have at the moment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm}


\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{The paper title}}}
\author{Author 1\\
Address of author 1\\
e-mail address: author1@gmail.com \\
Author 2\\
Address of author 2\\
e-mail address: author2@gmail.com 
}

\date{}
\maketitle 
\abstract {Abstract goes here.}\\
\noindent {Keywords: }
\section{Introduction}

\section{Main Result}
\section*{Acknowledgement}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can manage the paper size and margins using `geometry` package. [http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry)

Comment: I downloaded the con­tents of this pack­age but still don't how to manage the paper size and margins. Can you give me some codes?

Comment: `\usepackage{mathptmx}` for the Times font, `\usepackage[rmargin=0.35in, lmargin=0.35in,tmargin=0.35in,bmargin=0.5in,paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in]{geometry}` for the geometry package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a possible setup, but I wonder a little bit about the paper size.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}%
\usepackage[rmargin=0.35in,lmargin=0.35in,tmargin=0.35in,bmargin=0.5in,paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in]{geometry}

\singlespacing
\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{The paper title}}}
\author{Author 1\\
Address of author 1\\
e-mail address: author1@gmail.com \\
Author 2\\
Address of author 2\\
e-mail address: author2@gmail.com 
}

\date{}
\maketitle 
\abstract {Abstract goes here.}\\
\noindent {Keywords: }
\section{Introduction}

\section{Main Result}
\section*{Acknowledgement}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to the OP's comment, it is better to use `article` instead of `scrartcle` class.

Comment: Many thanks for your help @Christian Hupfer. The problem with format is solved. But other small issue comes out: the page numbers weren't be showed.

Comment: @Gooner: One problem is the definitely the very small bottom margin. I try to correct it.

Comment: If you use `article` class then the problem of pagenumbering is solved.

Comment: @Gooner: Yes, you are right. I will update my answer.